# What is the dimension of $V\times W$, where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\dim V=m$ and let $\dim W=n.$ Then I believe that $\dim (V\times W)=m+n.$ However, the author of my book says that the answer should be $mn.$ Just to be double sure, here is the definition that he provides:

[image]

If $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_m\}$ forms the basis for $V$ and $\{\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_n\}$ forms the basis for $W$ then we have that for any $(v,w)\in V\times W$ $$(v,w)=(\sum_{i=1}^{m}A_i\alpha_i,\sum_{j=1}^{n}B_j\beta_j)=(\sum_{i=1}^{m}A_i\alpha_i,0_W)+(0_V,\sum_{j=1}^{n}B_j\beta_j).$$ And so we have that $$\{(\alpha_1,0_W),(\alpha_2,0_W)...,(\alpha_m,0_W),(0_V,\beta_1),(0_V,\beta_2),...,(0_V,\beta_n)\}$$ is a basis for $V\times W.$ But here is what the solution to $1.31$ part (c) of the problem looks like:

[image]

Comment: A quick check. We have $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. Is the dimension of $\mathbb R^2$ equal to $1$ or is it equal to $2$?

Comment: Which book ? $~~~$

Comment: Looks like a typo...

Comment: @A---B Linear Algebra Challenging Problem Book by Fuzhen Zhang.

Comment: @Fabian maybe, but all the solutions in the exercise are based on this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct and the book is wrong. The dimension of $V\times W$ is $m+n$. The space with dimension $mn$ is actually the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) $V \otimes W$, which you should meet pretty later.

Comment: So the dimension of $M_2(\mathbb{R})\times M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $4+4=8$, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. You already did the general construction: if $E_{ij}$ is the $2 \times 2$ matrix with $1$ in the entry $(i,j)$ and zero everywhere else, then $\{ E_{ij} \mid 1 \leq i,j \leq 2 \}$ is a basis for $M_2(\Bbb R)$. By your (correct) calculations, $\{(E_{ij}, 0), (0,E_{k\ell}) \mid 1 \leq i,j,k,\ell \leq 2\}$ is a basis for the product $M_2(\Bbb R) \times M_2(\Bbb R)$. That last set has $8$ elements.